# Removing features from tinymce editor

Tags: jquery, html, css, tinymce

I had used an editor tinymce.
https://www.tinymce.com/

but, unfortunately I need to remove some default tools in tinymce like (file, edit, etc).

Comment: Please go through the reference: https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/editor-appearance/#removed_menuitems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove menus from tinymce like below

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea',  // change this value according to your HTML
    removed_menuitems: 'file, edit'
});
```